# How can I only show the exact lines from a file with a keyword?

Tags: php, fopen, fread

I am looking for a way to only show certain strings with the help of a keyword from a file. So for example if someone inputs a certain playername in a textfield only the commands done by that player will be shown from the logfile.

### Logfile

```
Command: .gm fly on [Player: PlayerOne (Guid: 135) (Account: 256) X: 16222.640625 Y: 16253.207031 Z: 12.735716 Map: 720 (Realmlist) Area: 0 (Unknown) Zone: Unknown Selected none: (GUID: 0)]
Command: .gm on [Player: PlayerTwo (Guid: 136) (Account: 257) X: 16252.911133 Y: 16232.371094 Z: 30.036341 Map: 720 (Realmlist) Area: 0 (Unknown) Zone: Unknown Selected none: (GUID: 0)]
Command: .mod sp 5 [Player: PlayerThree (Guid: 137) (Account: 258) X: 16252.911133 Y: 16232.371094 Z: 30.036341 Map: 720 (Realmlist) Area: 0 (Unknown) Zone: Unknown Selected none: (GUID: 0)]
```

### PHP Script I have so far

It only dumps the whole GM.log file for now.

```
$logfile = "/logs/GM.log"; // Directory where the GM.log is stored.

$file = fopen($logfile, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

$read = fread($file,filesize($logfile));
    
    echo nl2br($read); //Dump the whole file for now.
   
fclose($file);
```

I am not asking for someone to code the exact code for me, I'm rather asking for hints on how I would do it the best way.

Comment: You can make a condition on every line and see if it contains your keyword, you can use this: `if (strpos($ine,'player1') !== false) {
    echo $line;
}`

Comment: FYI: You can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works and where everything is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

Just get your file into an array via [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then use simply [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to identify the lines you want.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("logs.txt");
    $lines = preg_grep("/Player: PlayerTwo/", $lines);
    print_r($lines);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [1] => Command: .gm on [Player: PlayerTwo (Guid: 136) (Account: 257) X: 16252.911133 Y: 16232.371094 Z: 30.036341 Map: 720 (Realmlist) Area: 0 (Unknown) Zone: Unknown Selected none: (GUID: 0)] )
```